# How to encode and license my laravel project using ioncube?

Tags: php, laravel-5, encoding, ioncube

I want to deploy my laravel project on our client machine which has no network access .I have to install it on his machine on local server. However I don't want to lose the source code if somebody tries to hack it.

Searched and found that ioncube encoder is a perfect solution. I did encode my necessary project files. It was all good until licensing of the product.

We are planning to give a 1 year license which can be renewed upon entering a pattern that he gets if he decides to continue with us(also if he pays).

[This user guide](https://www.ioncube.com/sa/USER-GUIDE.pdf) helps me till **encoding and first time licensing of the product**. I am using laravel 5.2 , mysql and angular for the project.

```
./make_license --passphrase **** --expire-in 1h --header-line '<?php exit(0);?>'
```

I have followed [this](http://kbeezie.com/generating-ioncube-licenses/) tutorial also.

Problem begins right from the license expiry. If license expires , server throws a fatal error. Capturing fatal error exception for licensing 'll hide all other fatal errors from me which is not ideal.

```
if($exception instanceof FatalErrorException)
{
    return response(view('error.license'), 400);
}
```

What is the best method that I can implement here, for renewing license?

Also how can I catch the fatal error exception of ioncube license expiry separately in laravel?

Thank you

Comment: You could use `--license-check script` which encodes to let code run even if a license is invalid. The script can then use API function `ioncube_license_matches_server()` to validate the license and decide what it wants to do. You might also use MAC address locking with Cerberus or use license key/value properties as part of a custom license checking scheme such as to validate the inode number of a particular file, where the file path and expected inum are properties of the file. Also, make sure to use the Dynamic Keys feature for best protection.  Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube.

Comment: ya. i found the --license-check script section and it solved  the issue of throwing fatal error when license expired also. As laravel is the most popular php framework now, I request you to provide a thorough documentation on the combination.Thank you for your support.

Comment: What is the best method of renewing license in laravel. I am currently using a middleware that compares time and then runs shell execute command to generate new license and replace key file

Comment: If you search for Laravel on the ionCube blog there are a couple of articles. I recommend creating a support ticket for guidance and proposing any new blog articles :)

Comment: Will do that. Thank you for your help